# delete entry or update as blank (i.e. " ") to JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I am trying to simply create a **delete function**, to simply remove the found entry in my JSON file.

So far the below is successfully finding the line (i.e. entry) I want to remove/`delete`, or update with blank `" "` - however I am having a hard time writing it back to the JSON file *removed*... It is fetching just fine, and I am find the line I want to remove just fine.

I believe it is a JavaScript question and something I am mishandling here, as I am using the `../processor.php` to write new entries to the JSON file just fine.

```
  // Delete Function
  dele.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    let e= document.getElementById("dropdown-of-entry");
    let slctn= e.value;
    console.log(slctn);

    fetch(urld)  
    .then(
      function(response) {  
        response.json().then(function(data) {  

          let gData = JSON.stringify(data)
          let jsonF = JSON.parse(gData);

          let findtempto;
          let jsonUpdt;
          let jsonUpdtd;
        for (let i = 0; i < jsonF.length; i++) {
            findtempto = jsonF[i].styleName;
            if (findtempto === slctn) { 
                console.log(jsonF[i]); // This successfully finds the line I want to delete
                //delete jsonF[i]; // No avail
                jsonF[i] = " "; // Am trying this next
                // I have also tried moving the ajax call here, and lines above it
             }
           }    
        });

        jsonUpdt = JSON.stringify(jsonF);
        console.log(jsonUpdt);

        jsonUpdtd = JSON.parse(jsonUpdt);
        console.log(jsonUpdtd);

        $.ajax({
          url: './php/data/processor.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: { template: jsonUpdtd },
          success: function(msg) {
              console.log('updated/deleted data');
          }               
        });  
      }  
    )  
    .catch(function(err) {  
      console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
    });
  });
```

Comment: If `jsonF` is supposed to be an array of objects, assigning a string to `jsonF[i]` will probably confuse other users of the JSON.

Comment: There's no need to stringify and then then parse.

Comment: I have also tried without stringify and parse.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array.filter()` to keep elements in an array that match a criteria.

```
jsonF = jsonF.filter(e => e.styleName != slctn);
```

Replacing an object with a string like `" "` will cause problems later, since the rest of the code expects the array to contain objects.